# Why is CSS changed in Firefox only when CSS is loaded from server?

Tags: html, css

My uploaded css is using `border: thin dashed` but Firebug is show the style as `border: thin solid`.

This is uploaded style

```
#menu a{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: thin dashed #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;  
}
```

This is CSS I see in Firebug

```
#menu a {
    border: thin solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

On local preview (F12-Firefox 16) `#menu a border` is dashed, but loaded from server, `#menu a border` is solid!

Comment: Are you sure this is the only CSS file/rule affecting the element? Maybe there are other CSS files included on the server.

Comment: @Cristy, I'm sure. I have four CSS files, but only one (index.css) is linked to this page.

Comment: Does it get changed on any other browser?

Comment: Are you sure your program (Firebug) isn't just making your CSS more easily readable? I havn't used the program personally - but the bottom CSS is no different to the top, it's just laid out differently.

Comment: @George, solid and dashed border are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like some caching is in play. Try clearing your browser's cache. If that doesn't work, add ?v1 to the end of the URL you use to call the CSS file. This will work as a cache buster. Ex: /assets/CSS/styles.css?v1

If neither work, I'd say you aren't uploading your CSS to the correct location.

Comment: @Alegro, remember you will have to change this query string value after every CSS upload if this is a server caching issue.

Answer (score -2):

Firebug consolidates your CSS as much as possible. So if you have:

```
padding-left:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
```

it will then show it as

```
padding: 1px;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. "On local preview (F12-Firefox 16) #menu a border - is dashed.
Loaded from server, #menu a border - is solid !"

Comment: Completely irrelevant. How does this explain the `border:solid` vs `border:dashed` in his question?

Comment: yes, I see that now...

Try changing the order of thin and dashed